# Cómo iterar por separado en una lista compuesta de tuplas

Tags: python, lista, bucles

estoy intentando iterar sobre cada elemento de la lista por separado, pero en conjunto dentro de las tuplas.
Ej: calcular el -1% de 15000, luego el 2% de 14850 y finalmente el -3% de 15147. Y luego el -1% de 15000, el -3% de 14850 y finalmente el +2% de 14404.5. Y así con cada elemento de la lista. El problema es que no sé cómo hacer para que empiece desde 15000 cada iteración de elemento de la lista, pero desde el valor de la variable capital dentro de cada tupla. Estoy intentando poner los valores de cada iteración de tupla separados para luego plottearlo por separado con matplotlib. Muchas gracias

```
general=[]
capital=15000
lista=[(-1, 2, -3), (-1, -3, 2), (2, -1, -3), (2, -3, -1), (-3, -1, 2), (-3, 2, -1)]
for i in lista:
    balance=[capital]
    for j in i:
        capital=balance[-1]+(balance[-1]*j/100)
        balance.append(capital)
    general.append(balance)
```

Answer (score 1):

En este caso solo tendrías que definir capital como 15000 al interior del ciclo for. Así, cada vez que comience a recorrer una de las tuplas el primer valor que calculará será con 15000 como capital.

```
general=[]
lista=[(-1, 2, -3), (-1, -3, 2), (2, -1, -3), (2, -3, -1), (-3, -1, 2), (-3, 2, -1)]
for i in lista:
    capital=15000
    balance=[capital]
    for j in i:
        capital=balance[-1]+(balance[-1]*j/100)
        balance.append(capital)
    general.append(balance)
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo también con numpy:

```
import numpy as np

lista=[(-1, 2, -3), (-1, -3, 2), (2, -1, -3), (2, -3, -1), (-3, -1, 2), (-3, 2, -1)]

lista=np.array(lista, dtype='f')

def general(capital,n=0):
    while n!=lista.shape[1]:
        lista[:,n]=capital*(lista[:,n]+100)/100
        return general(lista[:,0],n+1)
    return lista

print(general(15000))
```

La salida sería:

```
[[14850.  15147.  14404.5]
 [14850.  14404.5 15147. ]
 [15300.  15147.  14841. ]
 [15300.  14841.  15147. ]
 [14550.  14404.5 14841. ]
 [14550.  14841.  14404.5]]
```

Comment: Le he estado dando vueltas a mi respuesta y no encuentro la manera de no complicarlo más de lo necesario sin usar lambdas, maps y magia negra. Es un puzzle interesante aunque no mejora ni tu respuesta ni la de Andres así que la he eliminado. Gracias por el aviso